# WPF MVVM and View inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have about a dozen different views, which are pretty much identical except for the names of the properties they bind to.  For example, the below sections are form two different views:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonName}">       
<GroupBox Header="{Binding PersonName}">
  <ComboBox Text="{Binding SelectedPersonName}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DisplayMemberPath="PersonName"/>
</GroupBox>
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding PersonEntries}"


<TextBlock Text="{Binding CarName}">       
<GroupBox Header="{Binding CarName}">
  <ComboBox Text="{Binding SelectedCarName}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" DisplayMemberPath="CarName"/>
</GroupBox>
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding CarEntries}"
```

Note that the only real differences between these to blocks are the names of the bindings used (Person vs Car).

I was thinking of maybe creating one BaseView class that the other views inherit from.  This base class would use generic enough binding names so that it can be reused, such as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DataItemName}">       
<GroupBox Header="{Binding DataItemName}">
  <ComboBox Text="{Binding SelectedDataItemName}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDataItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" DisplayMemberPath="DataItemName"/>
</GroupBox>
<igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding DataItemEntries}"
```

This way, my PersonsView and CarsView can inherit from BaseView and that's it.  I would also have to make changes to the ViewModels though, so that they expose the correctly named properties, such as DataItem.  I guess I could create a base ViewModel interface that exposes the desired properties and have the other ViewModels implement that.

Any thoughts on the above?  Would it be a bad idea to try to create a base view or base view model as I described?

Thanks.

Comment: I have previously used a similar setup with good results. I'd say this is highly subjective and depending on the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're really going to create the inheritance in your view models, not your views.  I'd define an `ItemViewModelBase` class that exposes `ItemName`, `Items`, and `SelectedItemName` properties and derive my view models from it.

The views themselves don't really "inherit" per se.  In fact, unless you need customization in the view, you don't need multiple views:  you only need one view that presents `ItemViewModelBase` objects.

Of course, if you do need the views to be different, you can do a certain amount of customization, e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CarsViewModel}">
   <DockPanel>
      <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top">Cars</Label>
      <local:ItemView/>
   </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is a cool idea for another reason.  Right now, if you don't provide a data template, whenever WPF presents an object it creates a `TextBlock` containing `object.ToString()`.  Implementing a generic base class gives you a way to globally override this behavior just by creating one data template, e.g.:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ItemViewModelBase}">
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

That's not easier than just overriding `ToString()` to return `ItemName` (which is where I'd start), but if (for instance) you want a `ToolTip` that displays detailed information when the user mouses over it, you just add it to this one template and it works everywhere in your UI.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I am working on creating an ItemViewModelBase class right now and have a question.  ItemViewModelBase is an abstract class and I want to define the appropriate properties (ItemName, Items, etc.).  My Items property is an ObservableCollection:  public virtual ObservableCollection<???> Items { get; set; }.  What would I put as the collection type?  The classes that derive form this base class will have different lists (<Person>, <Car>).  Is the base view model the right place to put the property?  I do want all of the derived classes to implement it so it seems so.

Comment: One other question.  Let's say I do not need any customization of my views.  I would only need one View in that case.  It is not clear how I would set this up.  Are suggesting is that I create a DataTemplate for ItemViewModelBase and a single view (user control) to represent it?  I have not used DataTemplates with mvvm before so I'm trying to figure it out.  Right now I use Unity to register my viewModels and when the veiw is created, the viewModel gets injected in the view.  How would I differentiate between the drived view models when I try to create the view?

Comment: As far as your first question goes, I'd start out making it an `ObservableCollection<object>` and seeing if that turns out to cause any trouble.  For your second question, if you create a `DataTemplate` whose `DataType` is `ItemViewModelBase`, it will be used to present all of your `ItemViewModelBase` objects unless you create a specific template for one of the subclasses.  Look up data template selection on MSDN for information about how template selection works in the absence of Unity; it's pretty robust.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can continue having one generic view model, but having, instead, multiple
data layers. This can basically help you to push complexity on data layer,which
is basically easier to test and debug. But everything is too context dependent.
Good luck.