# MVVM and DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I had asked a question about mapping multiple view models to a single view ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557919/wpf-mvvm-and-view-inheritance)).  I got some good answers but I am still having some trouble applying what I learned there to my particular case.

A brief recap:  I want to create a base ItemViewModelBase class that exposes properties that my view will bind to.  Then I will create two specific view models, PeopleViewModel and CarsViewModel.  Both of these inherit from ItemViewModelBase and implement the appropriate properties.  Now, I want to be able to create a single view that will display the appropriate info based on which view model it is bound to.  Since both the PeopleViewModel and CarsViewModel expose the same properties and I want the view to look the same for both of these, I only need one view.

One of the answers in my previous question suggested using a DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ItemViewModelBase}">
   //some user control
</DataTemplate>
```

I am new to using DataTemplates with MVVM (and MVVM in general) so I have a few questions:

Right now ItemViewModelBase is an abstract class and I defined the appropriate properties (ItemName, Items, etc.). My Items property is an ObservableCollection:

```
public virtual ObservableCollection<???> Items { get; set; }
```

- What would I put as the collection type? The classes that derive from this base class will have different lists (Person, Car). Is the base view model the right place to put the property? I do want all of the derived classes to implement it so it seems so.  ANd it doesn't make sense to have Person and Car extend some base object.
- Let's say I do not need any customization of my views. I would only need one View in that case. It is not clear how I would set this up. Should I create a DataTemplate for ItemViewModelBase and a single view (user control) to represent it? Right now I use Unity to register my view models and when the view is created, the view model gets injected in the view. How would I differentiate between the different view models when I try to create the view?

Basically, I don't know how to show the appropriate view when using DataTemplates.  In my application right now I have a window that contains a tab control defined like this:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}"/>
</Grid>
```

The TabControl's style contains the below setters:

```
<Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}"/>
```

TabItems is defined like so:

```
public ObservableCollection<ConfigTabItem> TabItems { get; set; }

TabItems.Add(new ConfigTabItem() { Header = "People", ResolveView = (Func<object>)(() => (PeopleView)Container.Resolve(typeof(PeopleView), "peopleView")) });
TabItems.Add(new ConfigTabItem() { Header = "Cars", ResolveView = (Func<object>)(() => (CarsView)ConfigurationModule.Container.Resolve(typeof(CarsView), "carsView")) });
```

So as it stands right now, I have separate view models and views for People and Cars, and whenever a tab is clicked, the appropriate view is resolved.

I want to change this setup to use the above mentioned base view model class and single view with DataTemplates.

Any sample code/sample would be greatly appreciated, showing a base view model class, some other view model classes extending that base view model, and then being able to show the appropriate view based on the view model (where there is only one generic view).

Comment: What mvvm framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking too much in a single question IMHO.  Try getting your code to work with or without DataTemplates (make it hacky if you need to) and then focus on ONE area of the code that you think needs refinement, and post a question about how to solve a specific problem.  I started typing out an answer and it quickly got too complicated to articulate an overall recommendation.

I'm not sure you got good advice in the other question about DataTemplates.  I'm also very concerned about how you have the ConfigTabItem set up--it seems to be a parent viewmodel that uses the container (directly, which is not a good practice) to resolve a view, which presumably also has its own viewmodel.  This seems needlessly complicated.

Anyway, again, try to distill it down to a few focused questions.  In the case that any of it is helpful, my original start at an answer is below (unedited):

---

First, I'm not sure I understand the answer you were given in your previous question that talks about DataTemplates.  If you will always be binding to a ItemViewModelBase, I'm not clear on why you need to specify a DataType (or even a DataTemplate).  This is not to say that using a DataTemplate is a bad idea, but I'm not sure I see the necessity of it in this case.

I'm also going to say that I'm not sure I see the *necessity* of inheritence either.  Databinding works at runtime, and outside of switching a DataTemplate based on VM type (which, as I said, I don't think you need), the view doesn't care what it is binding to, so long as the properties it is looking for are found at runtime.

So as a general matter, I would start with ONE concrete implementation of your view model.  Get it to bind correctly, and then determine which parts of it you can abstract into a base class or interface *if* that's the approach you want to take.  It's not necessary, but might help make the requirements for binding easier to "enforce"--for example, using the base class or interface will restrict you (or someone else) from changing the name of a property needed for binding.

> What would I put as the collection
>   type? The classes that derive from
>   this base class will have different
>   lists (Person, Car). Is the base view
>   model the right place to put the
>   property? I do want all of the derived
>   classes to implement it so it seems
>   so. ANd it doesn't make sense to have
>   Person and Car extend some base
>   object.

If you are going to use a base class or interface for your VM and you want the collection to be a part of it, it can simply be of type `ObservableCollection<object>`.  The items added to it will need to all have property names that match what you reference in your XAML.  So you can't have "PersonName" and "CarName" properties if you want only one view; you would need to use something more general like "ItemName" (unless you use DataTemplates with DataTypes--this is where that actually *would* be useful).  Again, you don't *need* each collection item to inherit from a base type or implement a common interface, unless (again) you want enforcement at compile time.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I will work on submitting more focused questions.  Btw, if I wanted to have a tab control where the content of each tab is a different view (with its associated view model) how do you recommend going about that (instead of what I have done with ConfigTabItem)?

Comment: From the code you posted, it seems like the tabs must be known up front. If that's true, you could create the tab items declaratavely in the XAML instead of programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Architecture from Microsoft App Studio for universal apps. According to Microsofts App Studio the DataTemplates should live in a DataTemplates Subdirectory under the Views Directory. A Universal app has this directory for both the Windows UI as for the Windows Phone UI so its not in the Shared project because they are not the Same. Don't use the Converge PRISM architecture. Its completely wrong designed! That was not written with a Windows and a Windows Phone architecture in mind but like they call it Converged. It should have been completely redesigned like it works in Microsofts App Studio. Don't look for Dependency Injection its not in it and not needed. Most use Dependency Injection for stub or fake interfaces. The DataContext for design data works now so good with json data that a Dependency Injection component would be overkill.